# Why is this cast not possible?

Tags: c#, generics, oop

```
interface IFolderOrItem<TFolderOrItem> where TFolderOrItem : FolderOrItem {}

abstract class FolderOrItem {}

class Folder : FolderOrItem {}

abstract class Item : FolderOrItem {}

class Document : Item {}
```

now i'm trying to do sth like this:

```
class Something
{
    IFolderItemOrItem<Item> SelectedItem { get; set; }
    void SomeMagicMethod()
    {
        this.SelectedItem = (IFolderOrItem<Item>)GetMagicDocument();
        // bad bad bad ... ??
    }
    IFolderOrItem<Document> GetMagicDocument()
    {
        return someMagicDocument; // which is of type IFolderOrItem<Document>
    }
}
```

is there any possibility to get this working?

Comment: what is the error message it throws? Compile time?

Comment: without a cast = compile time; with cast = run time

Comment: (note per your comment on my reply, I added some notes on a non-generic base interface that at least gets it working)

Comment: @downvoter: it would be interesting why ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If I read it correctly... then the problem is that just because `Foo : Bar`, that does **not** mean that `ISomething<Foo> : ISomething<Bar>`...

In some cases, variance in C# 4.0 may be an option. Alternatively, there are sometimes things you can do with generic methods (not sure it will help here, though).

---

The closest you can do in C# 3.0 (and below) is probably a non-generic base interface:

```
interface IFolderOrItem {}
interface IFolderOrItem<TFolderOrItem> : IFolderOrItem
    where TFolderOrItem : FolderOrItem { }
```

commonly, the base-interface would have, for example, a `Type ItemType {get;}` to indicate the real type under consideration. Then usage:

```
IFolderOrItem SelectedItem { get; set; }
...
public void SomeMagicMethod()
{
    this.SelectedItem = GetMagicDocument(); // no cast needed
    // not **so** bad
}
```

---

From the spec, this relates to §25.5.6 (ECMA 334 v4):

> 25.5.6 Conversions
>
> Constructed types follow the same conversion rules (§13)
>   as do non-generic types. When applying
>   these rules, the base classes and
>   interfaces of constructed types shall
>   be determined as described in §25.5.3.
>
> No special conversions exist between
>   constructed reference types other than
>   those described in §13. In particular,
>   unlike array types, constructed
>   reference types do not permit
>   co-variant conversions (§19.5). This
>   means that a type `List<B>` has no
>   conversion (either implicit or
>   explicit) to `List<A>` even if `B` is
>   derived from `A`. Likewise, no
>   conversion exists from `List<B>` to
>   `List<object>`.
>
> [Note: The rationale for
>   this is simple: if a conversion to
>   `List<A>` is permitted, then apparently,
>   one can store values of type `A` into
>   the list. However, this would break
>   the invariant that every object in a
>   list of type `List<B>` is always a value
>   of type `B`, or else unexpected failures
>   can occur when assigning into
>   collection classes. end note]

The same applies to interfaces. This changes a *bit* in C# 4.0, but only in some cases.

Comment: Tricky... it *isn't* an IFolderOrItem<Item> - so unless you wrap it, is isn't going to work. Depending on what the members in the interface are, it *might* work (with an extra modifier) in 4.0. Other than that... perhaps declare a non-generic interface...

Comment: your solution of generic free interface combined with an abstract class (generic free one + generic one) just hits the nail ... wow! thank you!

Answer (score 6):

As far as the compiler is concerened, `IFolderOrItem<Document>` & `IFolderOrItem<Item>` are two completely different types.

`Document` may inherit `Item`, but `IFolderOrItem<Document>` does not inherit `IFolderOrItem<Item>`

I'm relying on Marc or Jon to post links to the relevant portions of the C# spec.

Comment: lol - but I believe this is one of those things that aren't in the C# 3.0 spec simply because it isn't a consideration. There should be something in the 4.0 spec, though.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that a cast does not work on the generic arguments, but on the class as a whole.  Document inherits from Item, true, but IFolderOrItem< Document> does not inherit from IFolderOrItem< Item>, nor is related with it in any way.

Answer (score 2):

An example to understand why it works this way :

Suppose IFolderOrItem exposes a method, for example, void Add(T element).

Your implementation for IFolderOrItem will suppose the parameter is a Document.

But of you cast your IFolderOrItem as IFolderItemOrItem, then someone could call the method Create(T) where T is supposed to be an Item.

The cast from Item to Document is invalid, since an Item is not a Document.

The only way for you to do this is to create a non-generic version of the interface, allowing objects as parameters, the check the type of the object in your implementations.